# Include namespaces in php , how it exactly works?

Tags: php, namespaces, include

While studying namespaces in PHP, I figured out that the below is the way of declaring namespace in PHP,

**File1.php**

```
namespace Web\Core;


function m1() {
   var_dump(__FUNCTION__);
}
```

And to use the declared namespace block of code, we must do the below :

**File2.php**

```
namespace Web\Core;
include 'File1.php';

m1();
```

I stuck at the below point :

- How include works here as include here must cause an error because nested namespaces are not allowed, as include here means :

**File2.php => After include**

```
namespace Web\Core;

namespace Web\Core;



function m1() {
   var_dump('Test Function calling');
}

m1();
```

and this is a reason for nested namespace error.

Another Example : 
**File1.php**

```
    namespace App\Lib1;

    function MyFunction() {
         var_dump(__NAMESPACE__);
    }


nameSpace App\Lib2;

    function myFunction(){
        var_dump(__NAMESPACE__);
    }
```

**File2.php :**

```
require ("File1.php");
```

and here will be the usage for both namespaces ,and this also means to declare two namespaces and use them in no bracketed namespace which is not allowed , So File2.php will look like the below after include:

```
namespace App\Lib1;

    function MyFunction() {
         var_dump(__NAMESPACE__);
    }


nameSpace App\Lib2;

    function myFunction(){
        var_dump(__NAMESPACE__);
    }

then use them.
```

**So, how include works correctly and how there is no clear explanation for this behaviour at the documentation even for beginners?**

Comment: include is including a separate file, it is not including into the existing namespace

Comment: You should not do this from scratch. Use an autoloader. And use a framework. Really.

Comment: @FiberOptic : this was a training for me to understand namespaces to check how Laravel uses them, and I couldn't understand the core usage way for moving to the next step, I read more than 15 article and nobody clarified how this works.

Comment: @MarkBaker : Actually, I didn't understand your comment, could you please create an answer with explanation and code snippets?